# Regular expression to delete row from csv

Tags: regex, csv

I have a line from CSV

> `first decimal;;;first text;;second text with newlines, special symbols, including semicolons;second decimal, always present;first dot separated float, may not present;second dot separated float, may not present;third text that present only if present previous float`

I need to delete second text (with new lines and special symbols).

As for now I have expression like:

```
(?<=;;)(.*?)(?=;\d+)
```

First part of it does not work, and I don't know how to make it select text preceded by only two semicolons (for now it selects text preceded by two or more semicolons and first decimal preceded by semicolons + newline if I turn on dotall). Besides, I do not know how to include newline symbol here `(.*?)`.

Comment: As Tim suggested in the last line of his answer, while it may be possible to make this work with regular expressions, always use the right tool for the job. Consider a CSV library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CSV file that contains semicolons and newlines as part of quoted fields, then regex is not the right tool for this. Imagine what would happen if you had a field like `"This is one field;;don't split this;42"`...

If you're sure that you'll never have two semicolons before or within a quoted field, then you may give regex a try. But a dedicated CSV parser would definitely be a safer bet.

That said, let's see why your regex fails:

Imagine the line `1;;;2;3`. Your regex will match `;2` because it fulfills all the requirements - there are two semicolons before it, and a semicolon plus digit after it. It's also the shortest possible match at this position in the string.

What can you do? You could use another lookbehind assertion to make sure that it's not possible to match three semicolons before the current position:

```
(?<=;;)(?<!;;;)(.*?)(?=;\d+)
```

Give it a try - but look into CSV libraries too, because they will solve your problem better.

Comment: Expression you suggested all the same selects first text (preceded by three semicolons).